# How to find and replace values of even-positioned elements in sequence

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a list as follows:

```
list_1 = [12, 15, 18, 21, 6, 9, 7, 21, 38, 62, 65, 68, 81, 21, 25, 96, 101, 8, 11]
```

There are sequences of elements whose value's distances are equal. In this list, that distance is `3`, for example, `12, 15, 18, 21`.

How can I replace the value of the even-positioned elements for each of these sequences / sublists with a new value, say -1. The output will be:

```
list_2 = [12, -1, 18, -1, 6, -1, 7, 21, 38, 62, -1, 68, 81, 21, 25, 96, 101, 8, -1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)

```
s = pd.Series(list_1)
s.loc[(s.diff() == 3) & (s.index % 2 == 1)] = -1
```

which yields

```
[12, -1, 18, -1, 6, -1, 7, 21, 38, 62, 65, -1, 81, 21, 25, 96, 101, 8, 11]
```

---

Now, if you want the even positions related to *each* of those sequences independently, use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
s.loc[s.groupby(s.diff().ne(3).cumsum()).cumcount() % 2 == 1] = -1
```

which yields

```
[12, -1, 18, -1, 6, -1, 7, 21, 38, 62, -1, 68, 81, 21, 25, 96, 101, 8, -1]
```

---

The difference will be the last `-1` in your example. The first solution assumes the `11` shouldn't be replaced because it's not in an even position in your `list_1`. The second solutions assumes it should be replace, because it is in an even position in the *sublist* `[8, 11]`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Question edited to make clear the replacement for even elements in each of the sequences / sublists

Answer (score 1):

For a numpy based approach we could use `np.diff` to find the first differences of the array, and check if the items are even by taking 2 modulo of an `np.arange`. We can then chain both conditions with a `bitwise AND`, and slice assign back to `a`:

```
a = np.array([12, 15, 18, 21, 6, 9, 7, 21, 38, 62, 65, 68, 81, 21, 25, 96, 101, 8, 11])

m = (np.diff(a)==3) & (np.arange(1,len(a))%2==1)
a[1:] = np.where(m, -1, a[1:])
```

---

```
print(a)
array([ 12,  -1,  18,  -1,   6,  -1,   7,  21,  38,  62,  65,  -1,  81,
        21,  25,  96, 101,   8,  11])
```